# Как лучше реализовать замену одного слова в строке из нескольких одинаковых?

Tags: java

Стоит задача вкл/выкл определённые сервисы при помощи radio button/checkbox с веб-морды, путём изменения текстового файла (в lua-скрипте меняется "true" на "false" и наоборот), для меня проблема в том, что не могу вкл/выкл сервисы по одному, а только тупо меню все "true" на "false", пытался через цикл "for", но что то не очень получилось, если вопрос звучит глупо и по детски, то заранее извиняюсь. Текстовик который нужно менять прикрепил.

```
CONNECT = 20
REPORT = 23
CONTINUE = 31
APPLYCHARGING = 35
REP_APP_CON = 233531

BYPASS_all_SERVICES = "OFF" -- OFF/ON

local SIP_TERM = {
SERVICE_BYPASS = true,
APP_SERVER_TYPE = "HTTP",
APP_SERVER_IP = "999.999.1.8",
IDP_RES = CONNECT,
ParamRequet = { "CALLING_NUM", "CALLED_NUM"}
}

local ROAM_CHECK = {
SERVICE_BYPASS = true,
APP_SERVER_TYPE = "ORACLE",
APP_SERVER_IP = "RADIUS", --настройки коннекта в /usr/lib/instantclient_12_1/tnsnames.ora 
IDP_RES = REP_APP_CON,
ParamRequet = { "CALLING_NUM", "CALLED_NUM"}
}

if BYPASS_all_SERVICES == "ON" then
print("\nContinue")
return 1, 0, CONTINUE -- Отправляем Continue

elseif SIP_TERM.SERVICE_BYPASS == true then
print("\nSIPOnly")
return 2, SIP_TERM.APP_SERVER_IP, SIP_TERM.IDP_RES -- SIPOnly

elseif ROAM_CHECK.SERVICE_BYPASS == true then
print("\nROAM_CHECK")
return 3, ROAM_CHECK.APP_SERVER_IP, ROAM_CHECK.IDP_RES -- ROAM_CHECK

else
print("Нет такого игрока") -- если BYPASS - ни одно из перечисленных
end

Appended Data
```

Comment: Не понятно о чем идет речь?

Comment: Речь о  включении/выключении сервисов, путём замены true/false в текстовике.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону RandomAccessFile,
вот как пример его использвания:http://devcolibri.com/2989